# How can I evaluate a series expressed with ellipses?

Tags: syntax, summation

I want to evaluate an series given with ellipses. For example,

```
1/2 + 1/(2 + 4) + 1/(2 + 4 + 6) + ... + 1/(2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 20)
```

Wolfram|Alpha works great, but how this solve on Mathematica?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you want Mathematica to guess the general term? If so, consider `FindSequenceFunction`.

Comment: Yes, but i want more. Sum with Sequence.
1/2+1/(2+4)+1/(2+4+6)+...+1/(2+4+6+...+20)+...

Comment: Use the Wolfram|Alpha Query option in the user interface input cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options to obtain your specific result:

```
Total[1/Accumulate[Table[i, {i, 2, 20, 2}]]]
```

or

```
Sum[1/Sum[2 j, {j, 1, i}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Both return $10/11$.

---

For a more general result, you could consider:

```
Sum[1/Sum[2 i, {i, 1, j}], {j, 1, Infinity}]
(* Out: 1 *)
```

Graphically, you can observe the convergence as follows:

```
ListLogLinearPlot@
 Table[{top, Total[1/Accumulate[Table[i, {i, 2, top, 2}]]]}, {top, PowerRange[2, 2^15, 2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]